# after compiling code JFrame does not appear

Tags: java, swing, jform

I'm using the Intellij idea platform.

I have the following code:

```
package GUI.test;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ramka extends JFrame{

    Ramka(){

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(100,100);

    }

    public void main (String[] args){
        new Ramka();
    }
}
```

I expected to see a JFrame after compiling this code, but was nothing appeared. What kind of problem can it be?

Also must admit, that I haven't possibility to run method "main". InteligIdea propose me only to compile Ramka.java. After compiling IntelijIdeay says, that compilation completed successfully, but thats all and is nothing happened. In my previous exercises I always ran method "main".

Comment: You appear to be putting the cart in front of the horse by trying to create Swing GUI's before knowing basic Java. I strongly urge you to go through an introductory tutorial on Java basics, such as can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html), starting at the beginning. There you'll find out how a main method can be structured, that compiling a program is not the same as running a program, etc. You won't regret doing this, believe me.

Answer (score 3):

You should do something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Ramka().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Besides missing the `static` identifier at `main`, you also have to make sure that your frame runs in the right thread check ["concurrency"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for swing

Answer (score 2):

You would see your Ramka if you actually ran main. Main should *always* be declared `public static void main(String[] args)` where you forgot the `static`. If you change it to:

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    new Ramka();
}
```

it should run.